# How to edit selected file in a dropdown list in textarea and then save it?

Tags: php, html

I have a script like this, let's call this page **select.php**:

```
<?php
........
echo '
<form action="editor.php" method="post">
<select name="file">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo.txt</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab.txt</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes.txt</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi.txt</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
</form>';
.........
?>
```

And I want to edit the selected file in another page called **editor.php** and then save it, how do I pass the `value` of the selected file to **editor.php** and then edit it in a `textarea`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP Open File - fopen().

```
 <form action="editor.php" method="post">
<select name="file">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo.txt</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab.txt</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes.txt</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi.txt</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
</form>


 if(isset($_POST["edit"])) {
   $filename = $_POST["file"];
   $myfile = fopen("$filename", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
   $filecontent =  fread($myfile,filesize("$filename"));
   fclose($myfile);
 }

<textarea>if(isset($filecontent)) { echo $filecontent; }</textarea> //echos file content in textarea.

 //write to text file
 if(isset($_POST["update"])) {
   $myfile = fopen("$files", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, $_POST["textareaContent"]);
   fclose($myfile);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you that works but what if my files are located at `/root/crt` ? when I execute your script it says `Warning: fopen(buzzmechat.ovpn): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/test.php on line 54` I know the error is caused that `buzzmechat.ovpn` isn't in `/www` directory. How do I tell the script that my files are all located at `/root/crt` ?

Comment: This means that file is not found. You set your file path in option value. Like, <option value="path_to_your_file">filename.txt</option>

Answer (score 1):

First, to make things simpler, I'll change your form so that it passes the actual file names instead of just a short version of it:

```
<form action="editor.php" method="post">
<select name="file">
  <option value="Volvo.txt">Volvo.txt</option>
  <option value="Saab.txt">Saab.txt</option>
  <option value="Mercedes.txt">Mercedes.txt</option>
  <option value="Audi.txt">Audi.txt</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

Next, editor.php

Please note: **Use a white list here!**  That's what $allowed_files is. You don't want a user to be able to edit any file on your system they want. Never trust user input! (Although really, this entire idea makes me really uncomfortable in general from security standpoint. I hope this isn't a publicly accessible script.)

```
<?php
$allowed_files = ["Volvo.txt","Saab.txt","Mercedes.txt","Audi.txt"];
if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(in_array($_POST["file"], $allowed_files)){
        $file_contents = file_get_contents($_POST["file"]);
    }
}

if($file_contents !== false){
    echo '
        <form method="post" action="save_file.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="file" value="' . $_POST["file"] . '">
        <textarea name="file_contents">$file_contents</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save file">
        </form>
    ';
}else{
    echo 'File could not be opened.';
}
```

Then you just have to figure out how to handle save_file.php This would receive the file name in $_POST["file"] (which you absolutely 100% positively need to validate against your whitelist again!), and it would receive the file contents in $_POST["file_contents"].

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for passing the value to the texteditor (editor.php)...

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{
    echo "<textarea>".$_POST['file']."</textarea>";
}
```

This results only the file name without extension, if you want to include the extension, you need to add `.txt` to the value of each `<option>`.